# How to use token between action chains, properly?

Tags: struts2, chaining, csrf-protection

I have an action which I should protect it from CSRF attack. I have used Strut's tokenSession Interceptor to achieve this.

```xml
<action name="showBranchSelection" class="action.Request.BranchSelectionAction"
        method="showBranchSelection">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession" />
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
    <result name="success">
        /jsp/customer/request/branchSelection.jsp
    </result>
</action>
```

and works great where this action has been called directly from jsp.

```xml
<s:form id="frmRequestShowBranchSelection" action="../../showBranchSelection" method="post" theme="simple" onsubmit="return false;">
 <s:token name="tknRequestShowBranchSelection" />
 <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

But I also have other actions (protected and not protected) which will be chained to this action in some situations.

```xml
<!-- not protected action chains to protected one -->
<action name="entranceCustomerLoginAction" class="action.Request.CustomerLoginAction"
            method="entrance">
    <result name="success">/jsp/login/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="showBranchSelection" type="chain"> showBranchSelection
    </result>
</action>

<!-- protected action chains to another protected one -->
<action name="continueReimTable" class="action.Request.ReimburseTableControllerAction"
            method="continueReimTable">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession" />
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
    <result name="showBranchSelection" type="chain">
        showBranchSelection
    </result>
    <result name="success" type="chain">
        showBranchPage
    </result>
</action>
```

What's the proper way to use token in such chains?! i.e. in both, when a not protected action chains to a protected action and when a protected action chains to another protected action.

Comment: Action chains not sure what you want but heavily maintained and thus discouraged. If this the subject to exchange the functionality by the action not properly ended at the both ends than you can still use Servlet's mechanizes to achieve desired behavior.

Comment: @RomanC I added sample codes to clear my want. Do you still advice to use Servlet's mechanizes? I would like to use Strut's abilities rather than lower level abilities as much as possible. thank you!

Comment: Chained action is more or less a result of the action execution. The interceptor could be configured to this action. You'd better read the docs to learn more about tokenSession interceptor to understand how it works.

Comment: @RomanC I understand how tokenSession interceptor works. I study even it's source. The token tag put a key-value in user's session when being processed in jsp and puts also token name and value into form. When form submitted to protected action, tokenSession interceptor gets token name and value from posted parameters and removes it from session. The thing which I do not understand is when a protected or not protected action chains to this protected action! i.e. this action may being called by three methods: 1. directly from jsp 2. from not protected action 3. from protected action;

Comment: It doesn't matter, you have to supply a parameters with the request, like in jsp code, but second the third cases aren't covered by you, so IMO it won't work without required parameters.

Comment: @RomanC so I think you mean Struts2 does not have a clear solution to generate token for second, third,... actions in chain and I have to generate a new token name and value for next action using TokenHelper and supply it to next as request parameter before returning the result from previous action method. right?

Comment: Each time you use a interceptor you should generate a token.

Comment: 1. You are missing `chain` interceptor. 2. Using `chain` result is discouraged. 3. What result do you expect?

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks! 1. It exists in real code 2. So what is the equivalent solution? redirectAction? 3. The project already finished and works fine without CSRF protection. They asked me for adding CSRF protection to it and I almost done all except chains! I just expect a protected action not return invalid.token when it has been chained from another protected or not protected action. (protected means having tokenSession interceptor inside)

Comment: @YasserZamani: Yes, the `redirectAction` is a better choice. From [owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet): *The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only respond to POST requests. This is in fact what the RFC 2616 requires for GET requests. If sensitive server-side actions are guaranteed to only ever respond to POST requests, then there is no need to include the token in GET requests.*