# How to add new parameters to action's context programmatically inside an action method?

Tags: struts2

From my previous question:
[How to use token between action chains, properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797459/how-to-use-token-between-action-chains-properly)
, Now I know that inside my action#1 method, I have to generate a token name and value using `TokenHelper` programmatically and add them to `ActionContext.getContext().getParameters()` before chaining to my action#2. If I do, then `tokenSessionInterceptor` in action#2 will consume this token and does not return `invalid.token`.

My searchs say if I use `ActionContext.getContext().getParameters().put` then I'll get following exception:

> Cannot find message associated with key parameterMap.locked

So I searched for `ActionContext.setParameters` usage. I see Struts itself has used it in one of it's interceptors, `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ActionMappingParametersInteceptor.addParametersToContext(ActionContext, Map)` as below:

```
@Override
protected void addParametersToContext(ActionContext ac, Map newParams) {
    Map previousParams = ac.getParameters();
    Map combinedParams;
    if (previousParams != null) {
        combinedParams = new TreeMap(previousParams);
    } else {
        combinedParams = new TreeMap();
    }
    combinedParams.putAll(newParams);

    ac.setParameters(combinedParams);
}
```

Is it safe to do same in my own action method rather than an interceptor?! If no, what are alternatives?! Is it possible at all?! I really need to do this in my action chains because it's so hard to rewrite these actions to use `redirectAction` instead of `chain`.

Comment: Usually you don't need to protect actions that doesn't change state.

Comment: @AleksandrM, yes I see. The second action in chain, changes something in database!

Comment: How generating token in action will protect from csrf attack? What is the use case of redirecting to action that changes state?

Comment: @AleksandrM, this action's method has some if statements. each statement returns different result. one of these results chains to an action which changes something in database and has been protected from `csrf` using `tokenSessionInterceptor`. other results do not need to being protected. you aware about my previous question which is linked to this one. According to that's comments, I have to generate token as parameters for next action in previous action's method before returning result. because I cannot remove `tokenSession` from next action's stack to this action one. because a jsp calls it

Comment: With that solution you don't achieve protection against csrf attack in case of unprotected action chained to protected one.

Comment: @AleksandrM, Ooops you're right :( thanks! So I'll add `<s:token name="sameAsProtectedOneName" />` in all JSPs whom have called unprotected action. While unprotected action does not have `tokenSession` in it's stack, then it does not consume the token and so, token reaches second chained protected action which needs it. If `chain` does not modify request original parameters then it should work without needing add new parameters to action context, right?